# How to parse github readme.md raw file content in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to parse readme.md file content using php to display content of my readme.md file.

for example I have below link for my readme.md raw file on github.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/makadiyaharesh/CLImageEditor/master/README.md

I already fetch the content of file but need to display on my website using PHP code.

Currently when i display this content that is not formatted.

Please help me to do that.

1) Read the full file content.

2)Display that content using php and display in proper formatted view as show on github.

Sorry for my english.

Please help...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 14):

`.md` files uses `markdown` syntax. you will need a `markdown` parser for this.
check out - [parsedown](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown)
hope it will help.

```
include('Parsedown.php');
$contents = file_get_contents('README.md');
$Parsedown = new Parsedown();
echo $Parsedown->text($contents);
```